# Deal with special characters in regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a list with this format:

```
var = ['A12232'], '['926596']','787878', '[WA-12333]', '[78888] [78888]']
```

I need to extrac the codes from this list, in this case those would be

```
A12232,926596,787878,WA-12333,78888 (just the first one)
```

I haven't found a way to deal with the " [' "  at the same time, I have try to use the '\' to scape it but only works with the first of them.

Comment: Is `'['926596']'` correct? Or you mean `'[926596]'`?

Comment: Is  ['926596'], I  put  '['926596']' to make clear that is a string

Comment: Why only the first `78888`? Because it is repeated in the same string?

Comment: Wait, so your list actually looks like `var = ['A12232', ['926596'],'787878', ['WA-12333'], [['78888'], ['78888']]]`?

Comment: When I print it I get this:  787878, '[WA-12333]', '[78888] [78888]', I need to eliminate the '[ and also get only one value is the are more than one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to strip leading and trailing quotes and/or brackets (your example is a little funny, since it's clearly not legal Python `'['926596']'` is garbage since it has unescaped quotes inside; perhaps you meant `"['926596']"`?), you don't need regular expressions, just `str.strip`-ing each piece and joining together:

```
codes = ','.join(x.strip('[]\'"') for x in var)
```

That just removes runs of mixed usage of any of `[`, `]`, `'` or `"` from the beginning and end of each string, then joins them together with commas.